# Can one create a Date32Array with pyarrow from 3 integer arrays for days, months and years?

Tags: pyarrow

Suppose I have three integer arrays:

- days: e.g. `[23, 12, 2]`
- months: e.g. `[3, 5, 11]`
- years: e.g. `[2008, 2011, 2019]`

Can one create a `Date32Array`, `Date64Array` or `TimestampArray` with `pyarrow` in a vectorized way?

I know I can e.g. create individual python `datetime.date()` objects and feed a list of those to pyarrow. I would however like to avoid a slow loop that creates a large number of python objects just to discard them in the next step.

Comment: I can't think of a way. If you had a date string you could use strpime https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/compute.html#conversions

Comment: @0x26res Thanks for your answer. I was worried that I was overlooking something in the documentation.

Comment: Pandas can take such input with `pd.to_datetime`, and then afterwards you can convert to a pyarrow array (if you are fine with using pandas for this step)